# Create an abbreviation page with `acro` package

Tags: acro

I am using a template copy from an [Overleaf chemical engineering unit operations lab report template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/ohio-state-chemical-engineering-unit-operations-lab-report-template/yrzjdvdnwsbd) and wish to add an abbreviation page. However, the styling doesn't apply at all.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{usa}{
  short=USA,
  long=United States of America,
}
\DeclareAcronym{eu}{
  short=EU,
  long=European Union,
}
\DeclareAcronym{ussr}{
  short=USSR,
  long=Union of Soviet Socialist Republics,
}

\begin{document}

\ac{usa}, \ac{usa}

\ac{eu}, \ac{eu}

\ac{ussr}, \ac{ussr}

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\linespread{1.6}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\graphicspath{{images/}{../images/}}

\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}

\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1in}

%-----------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}


\subfile{sections/01-titlepage}
\subfile{sections/02-abstract}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\listoftables
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\subfile{sections/03-purpose}
\subfile{sections/04-introduction}
\subfile{sections/05-experimentaldescription}
\subfile{sections/06-resultsanddiscussion}
\subfile{sections/07-erroranalysis}
\subfile{sections/08-conclusion}
\subfile{sections/09-recommendations}
\subfile{sections/10-designextension}
\subfile{sections/11-notation}

\section{Literature Cited}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{refs.bib}
\clearpage

\subfile{sections/12-appendix}

\end{document}
```

I expected it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE! Unfortunately, we cannot compile your code as your document class is `\documentclass[../main.tex]` and we do not have access to `main.tex`, could you please see if your questions issue persists with the `article`/`book` class or edit in enough of `main.tex` so we can compile it please?

Comment: I added the main.tex and updated the link of that template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling your given subfile I get the list of acronyms as expected, matching (as far as I can tell) the included image of what you expect.
However, compiling `main.tex` I see an error in the log

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.19 \ac
        {usa}, \ac{usa}
?
```

which implies [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) has not been loaded.
This is exactly the case, as `main.tex` lacks `\usepackage{acro}`, and while the line appears in your subfile, the [`subfiles`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subfiles) package ignores the preamble of any `\subfile{foo}` when compiling the main file.

In order for [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) to be used in the main document it needs to be loaded (along with all the `\DeclareAcronym`s) in the global preamble of `main.tex`.
This can be done either directly or through `\input{acronyms.tex}` to insert the necessary code from a separate `acronyms.tex` file.